# CodeDeploy Error : Fail to remove instance from Loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I am getting below code deploy error in AWS Console

```
LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop
Script - scripts/deregister_from_elb.sh
[stderr]Running AWS CLI with region: us-east-1
[stderr]Started deregister_from_elb.sh at 2020-01-21 10:53:43
[stderr]Checking that user set at least one load balancer
[stderr]Checking validity of load balancer named 'lb'
[stderr]Checking health of 'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' as known by ELB 'lb'
[stderr]Checking status of instance 'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' in load balancer 'lb'
[stderr]Deregistering i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx from lb
[stderr]Waiting for instance to de-register from its load balancers
[stderr]Checking 2 times, every 70 seconds, for instance i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx to be in state OutOfService
[stderr]Checking status of instance 'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' in load balancer 'lb'
[stderr]Instance is currently in state: InService
[stderr]Checking status of instance 'i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' in load balancer 'lb'
[stderr]Instance is currently in state: InService
[stderr]Instance failed to reach state, OutOfService within 140 seconds
[stderr][FATAL] Failed waiting for i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx to leave lb
```

While checking code-deploy agent log file in EC2 Instance its showing

```
ERROR [codedeploy-agent(14347)]: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Error during perform: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::ScriptError - Script at specified location: scripts/deregister_from_elb.sh failed with exit code 1 -
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:183:in `execute_script'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:117:in `each'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:117:in `block in execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:208:in `create_script_log_file_if_needed'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/hook_executor.rb:115:in `execute'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:158:in `block (3 levels) in map'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:146:in `each'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:146:in `block (2 levels) in map'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_executor.rb:68:in `execute_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:114:in `process_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:96:in `acknowledge_and_process_command'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/lib/instance_agent/plugins/codedeploy/command_poller.rb:75:in `block in perform'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:348:in `call'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:348:in `run_task'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:337:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `loop'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `catch'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `block in create_worker'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/logging-1.8.2/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:323:in `call'
/opt/codedeploy-agent/vendor/gems/logging-1.8.2/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:323:in `block in create_with_logging_context'
2020-01-21 10:54:56 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(14347)]:
InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Calling PutHostCommandComplete: "Code Error" 
2020-01-21 10:54:56 WARN  [codedeploy-agent(14347)]: 
InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPoller: Calling PutHostCommandComplete: "Code Error" 
2020-01-21 10:54:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(14347)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_deb.
2020-01-21 10:54:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(14347)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.0-1.1597_deb.
2020-01-21 10:54:56 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(14347)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.186875 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":5,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"Script at specified location: scripts/deregister_from_elb.sh failed with exit code 1\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"1YmxpYzAwMS9hcm46YXdzOnNkczp1cy1lYXN0LTE6MTMxMjE0OTI1MjQ1OmRlcGxveW1lbnQvZC1LVjgyTVRPNTIiLCJob3N0SWQiOiJhcm46YXdzOmVjMjp1cy1lYXN0LTE6MTMxMjE0OT1MjQ1Omluc3RhbmNlL2ktMDFhMGFiMjlhMWM2NjEwNjJ8MXwwIiwiY29tbWFuZE5hbWUiOiJBcHBsaWNhdGlvblN0b3AiLRleCI6MX0=")
```

I solved the issue temporarily by removing all the contents in /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root folder and restarting code-deploy agent service. But the issue get repeating after some time. Did any one know why is it occuring ?.

Comment: The script `scripts/deregister_from_elb.sh` is exiting with an error code 5 which means access denied. I would check that script and try to see what exactly it's doing.

Comment: Is that your script?

Comment: I am using aws sample script : http://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/samples/latest/SampleApp_ELB_Integration.zip

Comment: The script is failing due to access denied error.  You would need to review code execution, in particular file operations. Add -xev flags to the !#/usr/bin/bash line, and try again. That will produce verbose logging and should show you where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

The script `scripts/deregister_from_elb.sh` is failing due to access denied error. You need to review code execution, in particular file operations. Add -xev flags to the `!#/usr/bin/bash` line (so it reads `!#/usr/bin/bash -xev`, and try again. That will produce verbose script error logging and should show you where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using this script:

- https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codedeploy-samples/blob/master/load-balancing/elb/deregister_from_elb.sh

Your best bet would be to look at CloudTrail events during the execution of this script to see any failing ELB calls ('DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer' and 'DescribeInstanceHealth' calls in particular). AWS CodeDeploy console gives you exact timing of when a lifecycle script is run. It seems the ELB is unable to cleanly de-register an EC2 instance.